# Generating dictionary of lists in a loop (3.2.3)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

I need to create a dictionary where will be key a string and a value a list. The trick is I need to do it in a loop.

My minimalised code looks like this at the moment:

```
for elem in xmlTree.iter():

  # skipping root element
  if elem.tag == xmlTree.getroot().tag:
    continue
  # this is supposed to be my temporary list
  tmpList = []
  for child in elem:
      tableWColumns[elem.tag] = tmpList.append(child.tag)
print(tableWColumns)
```

This prints only the list created in the last iteration.

Problem apparently lies in the fact that whenever I change the list, all of its references are changed as well. I Googled that. What I haven't Googled though is the way how can I deal with it when using a loop.

The solution I am supposed to use when I want to keep the list is to copy it to some other list and then I can change the original one without losing data. What I don't know is how do I do it, when I basically need to do this dynamically.

Also I am limited to use of standard libraries only.

Comment: "Problem apparently lies in the fact that whenever I change the list, all of its references are changed as well." No; that can be a problem if you reuse the same list multiple times, but that's not what you're doing. (If it _were_ your problem, the simplest way to make a new copy of the list instead of reusing the same list is to slice it—e.g., use `tmpList[:]` instead of `tmpList`. But, again, that's not your problem.)

Comment: Also, your code doesn't do what you say it does—you don't get only the list created in the last iteration, you get `None` for every value. A minimal example is great, but it has to actually demonstrate the problem you're asking for help with. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the Help for more info on how to create good examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because of that you are creating the `tmpList = []` list in each iteration and put it `[]`.So python replace the new with older in each iteration, thus you see the last iteration result in your list.

Instead you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) :

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(list)

for elem in xmlTree.iter():
  # skipping root element
  if elem.tag == xmlTree.getroot().tag:
    continue
  # this is supposed to be my temporary list
  for child in elem:
      d[elem.tag].append(child.tag)
print(tableWColumns)
```

Or you can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method :

```
d={}
for elem in xmlTree.iter():
  # skipping root element
  if elem.tag == xmlTree.getroot().tag:
    continue
  # this is supposed to be my temporary list
  for child in elem:
      d.setdefault(elem.tag,[]).append(child.tag)
print(tableWColumns)
```

Also note as @abarnert says `tmpList.append(child.tag)` will return `None`.so after assignment actually python will assign `None` to `tableWColumns[elem.tag]`.

Comment: That's only a small part of his problem; that would mean that each repeated tag only shows the results from the last copy of the tag, but what actually happens is that each tag ends up with `None`.

Comment: @abarnert oops yeah!!! first time that i see the question i noted that! then forgot to mention it! thanks for reminding! also im happy that you came back to SO after long time ;)

Answer (score 1):

The big problem here is that `tmpList.append(child.tag)` returns `None`. In fact, almost all mutating methods in Python return `None`.

To fix that, you can either do the mutation, then insert the value in a separate statement:

```
for child in elem:
    tmpList.append(child.tag)
tableWColumns[elem.tag] = tmpList
```

… or not try to mutate the list in the first place. For example

```
tableWColumns[elem.tag] = tmpList + [child.tag for child in elem]
```

---

That will get rid of your all-values-are-`None` problem, but then you've got a new problem. If any tag appears more than once, you're only going to get the children from the last copy of that tag, not from all copies. That's because you build a new list each time, and reassign `tableWColumns[elem.tag]` to that new list, instead of modifying whatever was there.

To solve that problem, you need to fetch the existing value into `tmpList` instead of creating a new one:

```
tmpList = tableWColumns.get(elem.tag, [])
tableWColumns[elem.tag] = tmpList + [child.tag for child in elem]
```

Or, as [Kasra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29669646/908494) says, you can simplify this by using a `defaultdict` or the `setdefault` method.